# cannot allocate vector of 10.3mb, even after using disk frame in R

Tags: r, rstudio

my laptop has 4gb of ram still facing such issue even size of total excel file is 322mb,is there
a issue with my ram or rstudio.
Grateful! for your help.

```
#concat direcrtory to file names
files<-str_c("C:/Users/91932/Downloads/archive (2)/Fitabase Data 4.12.16-5.12.16",files)

# applying function to each element of vector

#map_df(.x = files, .f = read.csv,)

combine.df = csv_to_disk.frame(files)
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your workspace and/or restarting R and RStudio?

Comment: Does it work in an empty Rterm (not RStudio) console?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is the exact error you get?   Are you running on windows or linux?  What did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things I do when faced with this problem are:

1. Close other applications that may consume a lot of resources (Chrome and some other browsers tend to consume a lot of RAM).
2. Execute the command `gc()` so that R frees memory, if it is the first element of your code can run `rm(list = ls()); gc()`
3. And if none of the above works, restart the whole computer and only work with R.